# Getting an error like function does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table `HVACLoadReports` with the JSON columns `HeatingLoads` and `CoolingLoads` with a data structure like the one below. I am using `PostgreSQL` as my DB.

```
{
  "Roof": {
    "Total": 0,
    "Latent": 23 
  },
  "lights": {
    "Total": 0,
    "Latent": 23  
  }
}
```

And I am trying to update to the below structure

```
{
  "Roof": {
    "Total": { "UnitId": "BTUH", "Unit": { "Id": "BTUH", "Name": "btuh" }, "Scalar": 0 },
    "Latent":  { "UnitId": "BTUH", "Unit": { "Id": "BTUH", "Name": "btuh" }, "Scalar": 23 },
  },
  "Lights": {
    "Total": { "UnitId": "BTUH", "Unit": { "Id": "BTUH", "Name": "btuh" }, "Scalar": 0 },
    "Latent":  { "UnitId": "BTUH", "Unit": { "Id": "BTUH", "Name": "btuh" }, "Scalar": 1 },    
  }
}
```

For this, I have written the below query, where I am updating the structure as mentioned above,

```
DO $$
  DECLARE batch_size integer := 10000;
offset_value integer := 0;
BEGIN LOOP 
UPDATE 
  ""HvacLoadReports"" reports 
SET 
  ""HeatingLoads"" = jsonb_set(
    ""HeatingLoads"", 
    '{Roof}', 
    jsonb_build_object(
      'Total', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""HeatingLoads"" -> 'Roof' ->> 'Total'
        ):: numeric
      ), 
      'Latent', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""HeatingLoads"" -> 'Roof' ->> 'Latent'
        ):: numeric
      )
    ), 
    '{Lights}', 
    jsonb_build_object(
      'Total', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""HeatingLoads"" -> 'Lights' ->> 'Total'
        ):: numeric
      ), 
      'Latent', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""HeatingLoads"" -> 'Lights' ->> 'Latent'
        ):: numeric
      )    
    ),
    true
  ), 
  ""CoolingLoads"" = jsonb_set(
    ""CoolingLoads"", 
    '{Roof}', 
    jsonb_build_object(
      'Total', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""CoolingLoads"" -> 'Roof' ->> 'Total'
        ):: numeric
      ), 
      'Latent', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""CoolingLoads"" -> 'Roof' ->> 'Latent'
        ):: numeric
      )
    ), 
    '{Lights}', 
    jsonb_build_object(
      'Total', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""CoolingLoads"" -> 'Lights' ->> 'Total'
        ):: numeric
      ), 
      'Latent', 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'UnitId', 
        'BTUH', 
        'Unit', 
        jsonb_build_object('Id', 'BTUH', 'Name', 'btuh'), 
        'Scalar', 
        (
          reports.""CoolingLoads"" -> 'Lights' ->> 'Latent'
        ):: numeric
      ) 
    ),
    true
  ) 
WHERE 
  reports.""Id"" IN (
    SELECT 
      ""Id"" 
    FROM 
      ""HvacLoadReports"" 
    ORDER BY 
      ""Id"" ASC OFFSET offset_value ROWS FETCH NEXT batch_size ROWS ONLY
  );
offset_value := offset_value + batch_size;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
END LOOP;
END;
 $$;
```

But I am getting an error like

> `function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, jsonb, unknown, jsonb, boolean) does not exist`

Could any one please let me know, why I am getting an error like function does not exist?  Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Go here [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html) and you will see the function signature in the error does match that in the docs.

Comment: Because the syntax doesn't allow for setting multiple paths in a single call... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html  If you want to set multiple paths you need to call the function multiple times (nested; `jsonb_set(jsonb_set(JSONB, path, JSONB, true), path, JSONB, true)`).

Comment: @MatBailie, Thank you, Is there any way to multiple paths in a single call?

Comment: No, you call it multiple times...

Comment: @MatBailie, Please provide a small example to show the same if you come across any.

Comment: It's in my first comment.

Comment: @MatBailie, Please post the suggestion as an answer, and I will accept it.